# heightForRowAtIndexPath =0 but it still display the label in its row

Tags: ios6, tableview, cell

I have a table view and I set all of the odd cell height = 0, In odd cell I had some labels. When it show up the table view, the label in odd cell appear in the even cell. Is there any way to make the label vanish? This problem happened in ios 6
p/s: 
in ios 7: it work right.
i already had the method  : [tableView beginUpdates]; [tableView endUpdates];

Thanks.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // show odd row
    if (selectedRow == indexPath.row) return 78;

    // hide odd row  and show even row
    if (indexPath.row %2 ==0){
        return 88;}
    else{
        return 0;}
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    if (indexPath.row%2 == 0){


        //user click on even row -> display the next row 
        selectedRow = indexPath.row+1;

        [tableView beginUpdates];

        [tableView endUpdates];

    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int index = indexPath.row / 2;

    if (indexPath.row %2 ==0){

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PhraseViewCell";

        PhraseCellVietnamese *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSString *phrase = [[phrases objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"vietnamese"];

        NSNumber *checkFavorite =  [[phrases objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"favorite"];

        NSNumber *phraseId =[[phrases objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"_id"];

        [cell SetInfo:phrase :checkFavorite.intValue :phraseId.intValue];

        return cell;

    }
    else{

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PinyinViewCell";

        PinYinViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSString *pinyin = [[phrases objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"pinyin"];

        NSString *chinese = [[phrases objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"chinese"];

        NSString *voice = [[phrases objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"voice"];

        [cell setInfo:pinyin :chinese :voice];

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you set clipping subviews to yes for cell's contentView?

Comment: how to set it? sorry because i'm newbie

Comment: `[cell.contentView setClipsToBounds:YES];`

Comment: I set this in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` but it didn't work.

Comment: How are you setting the height of tableview cell? Please put in that code in your question.

Comment: i put all the code thanks for your help

Answer (score 25):

[cell setClipsToBounds:YES]; in cellForRowAtIndexPath

worked for me. Hope you found your solution.

Comment: Nice solution, Thx!

Answer (score 4):

After reading user2799736 answer I changed 
Clip Subviews
to YES in .xib file.
Worked for me.

Comment: Nice solution, Thx!